# Create GraphQL query in python

Tags: python, graphql

I would like to modify this string:

```
query = """
    mutation { 
     productUpdate(input: {id: "gid://shopify/Product/463...03", title: "test", descriptionHtml: "Amazing product"}) {
       product {
         id
       }
       userErrors {
         field
         message
        }
      }
     }
  """
```

I'm trying to put a variable in the place of "test" and "Amazing product". Normally i would do this with f-strings, but because of the GraphQL brackets i cannot do this.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can double up the curly braces to escape them:

```
my_title = "The Title"
my_description = "The description"

query = f"""
    mutation {{ 
     productUpdate(input: {{id: "gid://shopify/Product/463...03", title: "{my_title}", descriptionHtml: "{my_description}"}}) {{
       product {{
         id
       }}
       userErrors {{
         field
         message
        }}
      }}
     }}
  """
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [graphql-python/gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql) package. It supports [variables](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

While fstrings are great, in case of graphql queries you can just use below format.

```
query = """
    mutation { 
     productUpdate(input: {id: "gid://shopify/Product/463...03", title: "%s", descriptionHtml: "%s"}) {
       product {
         id
       }
       userErrors {
         field
         message
        }
      }
     }
  """ % ('test', 'Amazing Product')

print(query)
```